# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code (Flutter)

Tags: xcode, flutter

Everythign seems working in my app. I build the android app successfully, but while I am trtying to build usinx XCODE, I am getting:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

I tried many ways, such as:

- Flutter Clean
- POD install
- Legacy Build

Here is the error screenshot: https://i.postimg.cc/7PdNtwvN/Screen-Shot-2020-08-29-at-8-58-30-PM.png

I also followed guide provided here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56507

Thanks and will be great help if anyone can assist.

Comment: have you find any solution then?

Answer (score 0):

in my case the reason  no enough disk space on the mac